# How to return the full comments when using the VSTS Api to get a list of commits?

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a script for using the [VSTS api](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits#get-a-list-of-commits) to generate a log of commits between two different versions, however the response from the VSTS api returns the comments as truncated. This is the most important part of the log for my purposes and as such would like to receive the comments in full from the api.

The response comes back like this:

[image: truncatedComments]

I could obviously loop through each commit Id and get the full comments by calling the api for each of these Ids, but as this script will be part of our release process I want it to be as quick as possible, and all those extra calls would add unnecessary time to the script.

From what I can see there is no way to get the full comments when getting the list of commits, but I'm hoping someone out there can help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use API 2.0 if you can, there is no 'commentTruncated' anymore.
All the messages are returned in full.
The longest commit message I came across was 770 characters, 105 words across 13 lines.

- Finding the repository id:  [Get a list of repositories](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/repositories#get-a-list-of-repositories)
- Get a list of commits, [by repository id](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits#by-repository-id)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the max comment length parameter to some high value did it for me:
_apis/tfvc/changesets?maxCommentLength=1000

Comment: but what is I'm using the C# nuget package? The GetCommitsAsync method doesn't support this parameter :(

Comment: didn't work for me Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.1